# can we include the partial view with html content stored in database #laravel

Tags: database, laravel, forms, view, laravel-8

For example data in Database as

```
<div>
@include('web.home')
<div>
```

and in Laravel view can we parse this data and partial view as
assumed `$test` is holding the data
`{{$test}} or {!! $test !!}`
not worked

I have tried to recompile the blade using
`Blade::compileString($test)`
again no luck

Comment: you can use a view composer and use it to fetch the web.home blade variables directly  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers

Comment: if you already passed $test to your view from the controller and just want to use $test in the include use @include('web.home', ['test' => $test])  then use {!!test!!} in web.home.blade.php